# swift osx webview input type = text not working

Tags: swift, macos

I created window and webview programmatically.

[image]

All buttons, radiobuttons are clicked normaly. 
But if I click to input and want to type text it is not clicking. Cursor changes, but focus isn't in input. Keyboard not typing. 
Right button on input works fine and i can paste text in it.

```
//
//  WindowCommand.swift
//  DeskAlerts
//
//  Created by mihail on 26/04/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Toolbarstudio Inc. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Cocoa
import SINQ
import WebKit
extension NSCoder {
    class func empty() -> NSCoder {
        let data = NSMutableData()
        let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
        archiver.finishEncoding()
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data as Data)
    }
}



class WindowCommand:NSViewController, WebFrameLoadDelegate, WebUIDelegate, WebEditingDelegate, WebPolicyDelegate, WebDownloadDelegate, WebResourceLoadDelegate
{
    var Coder: NSCoder?

    var Window: NSWindow?

    init() {
        Coder = NSCoder.empty()
        super.init(coder: Coder!)!
        InitParentWindow()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func InitParentWindow()
    {
        let rect = NSRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 500.0 , height: 500.0)
        Window = NSWindow(contentRect: rect , styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask.borderless, backing: NSBackingStoreType.retained, defer: false, screen: MainScreen)


        Window?.isOpaque = true
        Window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        Window?.hasShadow = false
        Window?.isReleasedWhenClosed = true
        Window?.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
        Window?.allowsConcurrentViewDrawing = true
        Window?.ignoresMouseEvents = false
        Window?.isDocumentEdited = true
        Window?.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow))
        Window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        Window?.contentViewController = self
    }

    func Close()
    {
        Window?.close()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let preferences = WebPreferences()
        preferences.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
        preferences.allowsAnimatedImageLooping = true
        preferences.allowsAnimatedImages = true
        preferences.arePlugInsEnabled = true
        preferences.autosaves = true
        preferences.cacheModel = WebCacheModel.documentBrowser
        preferences.isJavaEnabled = true
        preferences.isJavaScriptEnabled = true
        preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        preferences.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        preferences.privateBrowsingEnabled = false
        preferences.shouldPrintBackgrounds = false
        preferences.tabsToLinks = false
        preferences.usesPageCache = false
        preferences.suppressesIncrementalRendering = true

        self.view.frame = NSRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
        CaptionBrowser = WebView.init(frame: NSRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
        let nillvalue:WebView? = nil
        if (CaptionBrowser != nillvalue)
        {
            CaptionBrowser?.uiDelegate = self
            CaptionBrowser?.frameLoadDelegate = self
            CaptionBrowser?.editingDelegate = self
            CaptionBrowser?.policyDelegate = self
            CaptionBrowser?.resourceLoadDelegate = self
            CaptionBrowser?.downloadDelegate = self
            CaptionBrowser?.windowScriptObject.setValue(HtmlInteropClass(data: Alert!, owner: self), forKey: "external")
            CaptionBrowser?.preferences = preferences
            self.view.addSubview(CaptionBrowser!, positioned: NSWindowOrderingMode.above, relativeTo: nil)


            var url = NSURL(string: (ParentWindowParams?.captionhref)!)
            CaptionBrowser?.mainFrame.load(URLRequest.init(url: (url! as URL) as URL))



            let mainbrowserwidth = 480

            let mainbrowserheight = 150






            MainBrowser = WebView.init(frame: CGRect(x:10 ,y:150, width:480 ,height:150))
            MainBrowser?.uiDelegate = self
            MainBrowser?.frameLoadDelegate = self
            MainBrowser?.editingDelegate = self
            MainBrowser?.policyDelegate = self
            MainBrowser?.resourceLoadDelegate = self
            MainBrowser?.downloadDelegate = self
            MainBrowser?.preferences = preferences
            MainBrowser?.windowScriptObject.setValue(HtmlInteropClass(data: Alert!, owner: self), forKey: "external")

            self.view.addSubview(MainBrowser!, positioned: NSWindowOrderingMode.above, relativeTo: CaptionBrowser)

            let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "Resources")
            url = NSURL(string: filePath!)
            MainBrowser?.mainFrame.load(URLRequest.init(url: url! as URL))


            //url = NSURL(string: Alerthref!)
            //MainBrowser?.mainFrame.load(URLRequest.init(url: url! as URL))
        }
    }

    func webView(_ sender: WebView!, createWebViewWith request: URLRequest!) -> WebView! {
        return sender
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNavigationAction actionInformation: [AnyHashable : Any]!, request: URLRequest!, frame: WebFrame!, decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!)
    {

            listener.use()


    }

    func webView(_ webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNewWindowAction actionInformation: [AnyHashable : Any]!, request: URLRequest!, newFrameName frameName: String!, decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!) {

            listener.use()

    }

    func webView(_ sender: WebView!, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String!, initiatedBy frame: WebFrame!) {
        print(message)
    }
    func webView(_ sender: WebView!, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String!, defaultText: String!, initiatedBy frame: WebFrame!) -> String! {


        return ""
    }

    override func loadView() {
      super.loadView()
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What did you use? Please show your attempt. Personally I'm using WKWebView and it works well.

Comment: @EricAya simple webview. Not wk. Tested with wkwebview - got the same.

Comment: `got the same` Yeah well now you can see that your issue is not with the webview. I'm using WKWebView and *it works*. So if it doesn't work for you it means you have another issue, it doesn't mean that webviews don't work. So you should show your attempt, show your code, and explain how you're doing things, because either you're doing something wrong or something's wrong elsewhere in your codebase/install.

Comment: @EricAya Thank You for your help. Added the code and picture with webview. Radiobutton clicks fine. but input can't be edited(( InitParentWindow - creating nswindow. And viewdidload - creating webviews

Comment: @EricAya Sorry for this. Edited code. It Compiles, shows views. All controls clickes, besides the input. Result - the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a trouble. 
Window = NSWindow(contentRect: rect , styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask.borderless, backing: NSBackingStoreType.retained, defer: false, screen: MainScreen)

if I making property 
styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask.borderless
Input is not availible.